# Nilpotent matrices and nilpotent level

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I would like to know what is a nilpotent matrix and nilpotency level? Are these matrices invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A matrix is nilpotent if $A^n$ is zero for some $n \ge 1$.  They are never invertible since their eigenvalues are all $0$. The elements of such matrix on the first upper subdiagonal i.e. $a_{i,i+1}$ are considered to be level one. The next subdiagonal is level 2 and so on.

Comment: What is the relevance to this question of the last two sentence regarding the subdiagonal?  Perhaps my confusion is from not understanding the meaning of "level" in this answer. AFAIK, "level" used in this answer is not related to the "nilpotent level" mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 1):

A matrix $A$ is nilpotent iff some power of it is zero, that is if there is a $k \in \mathbb N$ with $A^k = 0$. The smallest such $k$ is called the nilpotency degree of $A$ (you call this level of nilpotency?).

If $A$ were nilpotent and invertible, we would have for $k$ with $A^k=0$ that
\[ \mathrm{Id} = (AA^{-1})^k = A^kA^{-k} = 0 \]
which is absurd.